# Trouble with Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to learn how to use AWS to host Java web applications, but I'm running into some rather basic trouble.  While I am comfortable with Java I have very little experience with web development.

The basic issue is that when I try to run a "Hello World" application on the server I get an error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 53

50:         <div class="section grid grid5 s3">
51:             <h2>Amazon S3 Buckets:</h2>
52:             <ul>
53:             <% for (Bucket bucket : s3.listBuckets()) { %>
54:                <li> <%= bucket.getName() %> </li>
55:             <% } %>
56:             </ul>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: FB27B69E08FA9469), S3 Extended Request ID: gx1ZB6oZkPRrZFS9uTcfWvLhpgPxAUCQwmhaYttLB9qbANdIaUWQVNNtThM+whQU
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:937)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:506)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:273)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3660)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3612)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:672)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Here are the steps which led to this point:
1) I created an AWS account and registered a domain.

2) I created an Elastic Beanstalk app with the default environment and deleted the sample app (which ran fine).

3) I installed the AWS plugin for Eclipse.

4) I created a username in AWS and generated credentials for it, and then entered those credentials into the Eclipse AWS plugin.

5) I created a new AWS Java Web Project.  The project by default appears to be a sort of "Hello World" app, so I didn't modify it.

6) I exported the project as a .war, and uploaded the .war to my Elastic Beanstalk app.

7) I tried to run the app from the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard and got the error above.

I figure it's probably useless for me to try to write my own code if I can't get the default code to work, but if there is a simpler way to get started I wouldn't mind hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further testing, I think the problem is that for whatever reason my Elastic Beanstalk app does not have permission to access other AWS resources.  I don't know why this is or how to fix it and if anybody knows I would still like an answer, but at least I have gotten a much simpler "Hello World" program to run without interacting with the rest of AWS.